# why does mbstowcs return "invalid multibyte character"

Tags: c++, c, utf-8, utf-16

`"קמ&quot;ד חיר!"` is the input string copy pasted from a print of the variable in gdb. Calling mbstowcs returns -1 with the other input as NULL. Any ideas on what's wrong/how to fix this?

`"\327\247\327\236&quot;\327\223 \327\227\327\231\327\250!\000\000\000"` is the string with non ascii characters in octal

The programs locale is C.

Comment: We need the hex dump of the string, not the copy&pasted text.  If you copy and paste the string, it won't preserve the binary data.

Comment: In what locale is your program?

Comment: `mbstowcs` is for interaction with your runtime. If you get the string by deserializing a source with a known encoding, you should use something like `iconv` from your known encoding to WCHAR_T instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mbtowcs function doesn't handle UTF-8 encoding, there isn't a locale you can set to have it translate UTF-8 to wchar_t. Therefore, I'll use Windows examples but the general idea is the same on most OS.

In the multi-byte character set world there may not be one meaning for a given octal value and there may not be one octal value for any given character.  What a particular octal value means and how a character is represented (or even *if* it can be represented) is determined by [locale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyzd2bce%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

When mbstowcs returns an error it is basically telling you that there is no wide character equivalent to the multibyte character passed in to it.  That might mean there is no UNICODE character (unlikely but not impossible) or it might mean that the locale does not define a character for a given octal value (or sequence of octal values in the case of multi-byte characters).

If you don't explicitly set your locale (by calling [setlocale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99tb11d%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)) then you get a locale based on your system configuration.  To retrieve your current locale you can call [_get_current_locale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3szh5e2z.aspx).  Once you know your locale, you can figure out what character (if any) a particular octal value represents and then you can figure out what the UNICODE equivalent would be (if any).

One way to identify a problem character is to vary the length passed in to mbstowcs until you find a single character that causes the error.  A brute force approach might be to start at length=1 and increase it until mbstowcs returns -1.

**Update July 25th**

From the comments discussion we discovered that the input string is (most likely) encoded as UTF-8.  While the original answer is correct (so far as it goes) it doesn't go far enough.  On Windows you cannot create a locale that will handle characters encoded in UTF-8.

When faced with UTF-8, instead of calling mbtowcs, we can call [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) using the code page CP_UTF8 but that code will only work on Windows...

```
BYTE bytes [] = {0xD7,0x99,0xD7,0x95,0xD7,0x97,0xD7,0x90,0xD7,0x99,0x20,0xD7,0x95,0xD7,0x9B,0xD7,0x98,0xD7,0xA8, 0x00};

int result;

// get length of converted string in characters
result = MultiByteToWideChar (CP_UTF8, MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, (char *)bytes, 
    sizeof (bytes), NULL, 0);

wchar_t * name = new wchar_t [result];

// convert string
result = MultiByteToWideChar (CP_UTF8, MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, (char *)bytes, 
    sizeof (bytes), name, result);
```

Comment: The string is actually sent to me via facebook, not generated locally. How then would I translate it?

Comment: The mbstowcs function doesn't know (or care) that the string being translated comes from Facebook.  All it does is look at the current locale setting and translate the string as if that were the encoding used.  You need to figure out what code page Facebook is using and then set your locale appropriately.  Or, better yet, use a Facebook API that supplies UNICODE strings instead of multi-byte strings.  That way there's no doubt about the encoding used and you don;t need to translate to wide characters.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fql_query_response xmlns="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" list="true">
  <user>
    <uid>100000022063315</uid>
    <name>0xD7 0x99 0xD7 0x95 0xD7 0x97 0xD7 0x90 0xD7 0x99 0x20 0xD7 0x95 0xD7 0x9B 0xD7 0x98 0xD7 0xA8</name>
  </user>
</fql_query_response>
This is the response from facebook. Somehow, IE/Firefox displays the data correctly. Is the code page specified here somewhere?

Comment: It looks like the contents of <name> might be encoded in UTF-8.  Are you expecting the name to be "יוחאי וכטר"

Comment: yea, but didnt you say that i needed a locale?

Comment: Yes I did :-(  The problem is I explained how mbtowcs worked and just assumed that mbtowcs was the right function to call.  The mbtowcs function doesn't handle UTF-8 encoding, there isn't a locale you can set to have it translate UTF-8 to wchar_t.  I'll try and update my answer in some useful fashion.

Answer (score 1):

I bet it will work if you set UTF-8 like so:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Everywhere but Windows, yes. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/x99tb11d(v=vs.80).aspx "If you provide a code page like UTF-7 or UTF-8, setlocale will fail, returning NULL."

Comment: @Justin Link now results in "Visual Studio 2005 Retired documentation".