# How to convert accented chars from command line to wstring?

Tags: c++, c++11, utf-8, wstring

I'm trying to implement an application where I would like users to enter accented chars on the command line. What I'm trying to do is to convert the char array into a vector of wstring.

I'm on Linux.

Here is what I got so far:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<std::wstring> parse_args(int argc, const char* argv[]){
    std::vector<std::wstring> args;

    for(int i = 0; i < argc - 1; ++i){
        auto raw = argv[i+1];

        wchar_t* buf = new wchar_t[1025];
        auto size = mbstowcs(buf, raw, 1024);

        args.push_back(std::wstring(buf, size));
        delete[] buf;
    }

    return std::move(args);
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]){
    auto args = parse_args(argc, argv);

    for(auto& arg : args){
        std::wcout << arg << std::endl;
    }
}
```

It works as expected with normal characters, but does not with accented chars. For instance, if I do:

```
./a.out Ménage
```

it crashes:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_create
[1]    30564 abort      ./a.out Ménage
```

The exception comes from the constructor of wstring because size = 18446744073709551615 (size_t - 1 I think) which seems to indicate that there is an unexpected character.

I don't see what it goes wrong ?

What I'm doing wrong ?

EDIT: It's going better

If I add

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

At the beginning of the program, it doesn't crash, but does output a weird char:

```
M�nage
```

could it be a problem with my console now ?

Comment: @PreetKukreti: Windows rarely has executables called `a.out`.

Comment: This may prove helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400597/why-does-mbstowcs-return-invalid-multibyte-character

Answer (score 2):

The `mbstowcs` function uses the character encoding from the current locale. You are not setting the locale, so the default "C" locale gets used; the default locale supports ASCII characters only. Also, you should check the return value of `mbstowcs`, so it won't fail without you knowing it.

To fix this problem, set the locale in your program:

```
#include <clocale>

...

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,""); // Use locale from environment
    ....
}
```

Comment: Or in C++, `std::locale::global(std::locale())`.

Comment: I just tried this now. It is a bit better. It doesn't crash, but it does output M�nage instead of Ménage.

Comment: Are you running with a UTF-8 locale and a terminal with UTF-8 support? Run `locale` to check your current locale.

Comment: @BaptisteWicht Beside setting the locale, you might have to call  `std::locale mylocale(""); std::cout.imbue(mylocale);` as well.